# Why precision is decreasing when multiply sum to other number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have encountered with following bug (or feature) in SQL Server.

When I use `SUM (*column*)` where `column` has a `numeric(18, 8)` type and multiply it to any other number (integer or decimal) the result precision is reducing to `numeric(18, 6)`.

Here is the example script to demonstrate.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Qnty numeric(18,8))

INSERT INTO #temp (Qnty) VALUES (0.00000001)
INSERT INTO #temp (Qnty) VALUES (0.00000002)
INSERT INTO #temp (Qnty) VALUES (0.00000003)

SELECT Qnty, 1*Qnty
FROM #temp

SELECT (-1)*SUM(Qnty), SUM(Qnty), -SUM(Qnty), SUM(Qnty) * CAST(2.234 as numeric(18,8))
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

The result of second SELECT query

```
0.000000    0.00000006  -0.00000006 0.000000
```

As you can see then I multiply SUM the result is 0.000000

Could anyone explain the strange behavior?

UPD. I executed this query in SQL Management Studio on 2000, 2005 and 2008 SQL Server.

Comment: Slightly off-topic (and it doesn't help your problem) but I believe `NUMERIC` should no longer be used in SQL Server - `DECIMAL` should take its place.

Comment: Thnaks for advice. But with the decimal the same result

Comment: I know :) Thats why I said `(and it doesn't help your problem)`

Comment: Selecting into peristanttable from #tmp and instpectings resultdatatype will show a fieldtype on Numeric(38,6), SUM(Qnty*1.0)  will lead to numeric(38, 9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aggregating a `numeric(18, 8)` with [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)  results in the datatype `numeric(38, 8)`.

How the resulting datatype is calculated when multiplying something with numeric can be found here: [Precision, Scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

The datatype for your constant -1 is `numeric(1, 0)`

Precision is `p1 + p2 + 1` = 40
Scale is `s1 + s2` = 8

Max precision is 38 and that leaves you with `numeric(38, 6)`.

Read more about why it is `numeric(38, 6)` here: [Multiplication and Division with Numerics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. But why max scale is exactly 6? Why not 4 or 8?

Comment: @VictorChekalin According to the link I added " we decided preserve a minimum scale of 6 in both multiplication and division".

Comment: Thank you. Found the following article useful (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769823/Losing-Precision-After-Multiplication-in-SQL-Serve)

Answer (score 2):

If you read [SUM's reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259238(v=SQL.80).aspx), you'll see that on a decimal column it yields a type of `NUMERIC(38,6)`. You need to cast the result of the `SUM` to `NUMERIC(18,8)` for it to work the way you want.

Executing `SELECT CAST(SUM(Qnty) as numeric(18,8)) * 2.234
FROM #temp` yields `0.00000013404` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

a technical explanation can be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/233f7380-3f19-4836-b224-9f665b852406

Comment: I read that whole thread and didn't find anything in there that would explain the observed problem.

Comment: then you havent read the explanations from Mat Henaire:
..., the result should be a numeric(77, 20). However, this is above SQL Server's maximum precision, so the result would need to be truncated.
An implementation decision was made to sacrifice some scale to gain more digits on the left side of the decimal point, up to a minimum of scale 6. So the numeric(77,20) is actually converted to numeric(38, 6). The same behavior happens for division.
That decision is based off the assumption that digits on the left side of the decimal point are usually more important than the ones on the right side.

Comment: which again is what Mikael Eriksson explains in his answer above

Comment: Why didn't you just post that in the first place (with a link to the source)? Unfortunately it still doesn't apply to the OP because his numbers are all `numeric(18,8)` rather than `numeric(38,10)`.

Comment: It does apply, the maximum is still exceed when the operations occur.