# Data type change in division SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the below query in sql server 2014, the output datatype seems to be different from the input data type

```
DECLARE @i DECIMAL(18,2) = 2 ,@j DECIMAL(18,2) = 8

SELECT (@i/@j)
```

Expected Output is : 0.25 
 But what I'm getting is : 0.25000000000000000000

May I know why this DECIMAL(18,2) is changed?

Comment: Standard behavior for decimal division.

Comment: You might want to read up on [precision, scale and length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190476.aspx), and specifically how they are defined for results.

Comment: You may `CAST`, `CONVERT` or need to create a variable with `DECIMAL(18,2)` to store this operation. like `DECLARE @i DECIMAL(18,2) = 2 ,@j DECIMAL(18,2) = 8, @k DECIMAL(18,2); SELECT @k = (@i/@j); SELECT @k;`

Comment: And for some of the edge cases you might be interested in, I explored them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25301737/15498)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below query.

```
DECLARE @i DECIMAL(18,2) = 2 ,@j DECIMAL(18,2) = 8

SELECT CAST((@i/@j) as decimal(18,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL-Server 2012+ You can use `FORMAT()` :

```
SELECT FORMAT((@i/@j), 'N2')
```

As @Damien_the_Unbeliever said, you should note that this will return the output as a string..

For lower versions try this:

```
SELECT cast((@i/@j) as  decimal(18,2))
```

Comment: Even on SQL Server 2012 and higher, you should generally prefer to stick with appropriate data types rather than converting to string, unless this is *specifically* for presentation purposes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've added a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT convert(decimal(18,2),(@i/@j))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this:

```
DECLARE @i DECIMAL(18,2) = 2 ,@j DECIMAL(18,2) = 8
SELECT (@i/CAST(@j AS FLOAT))
```

OR

```
DECLARE @i DECIMAL(18,2) = 2 ,@j DECIMAL(18,2) = 8
SELECT CAST((@i/@j) AS FLOAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190476.aspx

Regarding Scale and Precision of a normal Division operation is as follows

Operation : `e1 / e2`

Result precision(Pr): `p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`

Result scale(Sr): `max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`

Where

p1 is precision of e1

s1 is scale of e1

p2 is precision of e1

s2 is scale of e1

In your case p1=p2=18 and s1=s2=2

As per the above calculation

Precision of output (Pr) and Scale of outpur(Sr) will be as follows

Pr = `p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`

Pr = `18 - 2  + 2  + max(6, 2  + 18 + 1)`

Pr = `18 - 2  + 2  + 21`

**Pr = 39**

Hence there has to be maximum 39 digits in the result. But

> - The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

hence there will be 38 digits.

As division result in decimal value less than one but greater than 0 it will give only one 0 before decimal point

Now Let calculate Scale (Sr)

Sr = `max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)`

Sr = `max(6, 2  + 18 + 1)`

**Sr = 21**

There has to be 21 digits after decimal point.
however as per maximum Precision value last digit in scale will be truncated. that's why in you result you have got only 20 digits after decimal point.

Hence the result **0.25000000000000000000**

If you want to get 0.25 the round the division using CAST or Convert as follows

```
DECLARE @i DECIMAL(18,3) = 2 ,@j DECIMAL(18,3) = 8

SELECT CAST((@i/@j) AS Decimal(18,2))
```